# Scraper to Database visualiser connector

Tags: web-scraping, google-sheets, database-connection

I'm using Dexi.io to scrape some data that outputs to Google Drive as a CSV, that gets parsed (through a Google sheets script) and added to a Native sheet (all automatically).

I'd like to push my data (automatically) to a "database Visualizer" of some sort (using knack.com currently) that allows me to display the data (in Table format) with some options to filter, sort and dig deeper; all protected by login creds that I manage.

I tried using Zapier to automate the Google Sheets to Knack integration, but Knack only has an option to "Create New Records" through Zapier and not "Update Records". (Updating records exists as an API endpoint)

I need help proceeding as I'm not a developer and am starting to hit the limits of my capabilities.

Could someone please recommend a tool (that integrates with Sheets, updates data periodically and lets me control the domain and login creds) or the optimal way to proceed with this? (I'd gladly hire a freelancer to help me build this out optimally)

Some more, potentially relevant, info: Dexi.io can output through FTP, Drive, Box or Amazon S3 (remember, not a dev :$)

Answer (score 0):

[kintone](https://www.kintone.com/) is a "database Visualizer" similar to Knack, and they have actions to update records.
https://zapier.com/zapbook/kintone/

There are two options to update records as there are two ways in which the unique key can be defined.

Each record in kintone has a "Record ID" associated with it - this is an autonumber made by kintone. You can specify this as the key to update, in which case you would use the "Update Record By Record ID" action.

If you would prefer though to set your own unique key and use that as the key to update, you can define that unique key in your database (I guess the data you are scraping has its own ID for each record). In this case, you can place a "Text (single-line)" field in your database, open up the options and select "Prohibit duplicate values" which will make this field into a unique field - meaning that no two records can hold the same value.
[image]

Once you set that field up (and update your kintone App settings), you can select this field to be the unique key to update for the "Update Record By Update Key" Action (the "Update Key" in the action name is referring to the unique key that you just made).

And yes, kintone gives you control over login creds, and each login cred can have different view/add/edit permissions over each record you have in your app.
You can also set a custom subdomain name, but the domain name will have to be kintone.com i.e. you can have a https:/ /mycustomname.kintone.com sort of name.

Hope this helps.